# Как в Facebook API получить текст всех комментариев с именем авторов?

Tags: php, curl, facebook, facebook-api, facebook-graph-api

Как в Facebook API получить все комментарии к посту и чтобы для каждого комментария был указан его автор?

Вариант, который описан в документации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

выдает только время создания, текст сообщения и ID комментария, а как раздобыть имя автора комментария?

**Неужели нужно делать отдельный запрос для каждого комментария?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С версии 2.11 информация о пользователях не возвращается, кроме случае когда у вас есть права на этой странице. Другими словами, ваше приложение должно иметь токен с правами на конкретную страницу, вы можете проверить это на своей странице, предварительно выдав разрешение.
Подробнее об этом изменении вы можете узнать [из документации](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.11#gapi-90), а здесь [похожий вопрос на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47736392/how-to-display-from-fields-in-comments-via-facebook-graph-api).

Временным решением может быть переход на версию 2.10, там пользователи возвращаются по вашему запросу.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]